# PHP-DI Call a method which have default parameter to null

Tags: php, php-di

I'm trying to use a **PHP-DI Call** on a method which have a default parameter but i get this error

**Fatal error: Uncaught Invoker\Exception\NotEnoughParametersException: Unable to invoke the callable because no value was given for parameter 1...**

PS : PHP-DI 6

```
  Classe Bill
  {

  public function index($slug=null,Request $request){
            //----
       }
  }

use DI\ContainerBuilder;

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder;
$container = $containerBuilder->build();

$controller = 'Bill' ;
$method = 'index';
$parameters = []; 
$response = $container->call([$controller,$method], $parameters);
```

Comment: Resolved by defining a parameter named "$slug"

Answer (score 1):

Works:

`class TestController {
    function doAction(Request $request, int $id = null) {}
}`

Does not work:

`class TestController {
    function doAction(int $id = null, Request $request) {}
}`

Source: https://github.com/PHP-DI/Slim-Bridge/issues/37#issuecomment-368954250

Comment: You might want to extract a summary from the link. It'll help the reader to get some idea about the thread without having to navigate to the link.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a value for the parameter `$slug`.

When a parameter is optional before non-optional parameters it cannot be omitted. So you have to provide its value.

Comment: @Mattieu Napoli thanks for the fastest of the answer, but i'd like to know..First is it possible  to make parameters  null ? two : if yes can i have a snippet as example , to make this work ?